# Vagrant Jekyll serve not available

Tags: vagrant, jekyll

I decided to try Jekyll, but as I have not used it I encountered a problem. When i serve it i get "This webpage is not available" on http://127.0.0.1:4000/. I'm using vagrant.

```
vagrant@ruby-jekyll-box:~$ jekyll new portfolio
New jekyll site installed in /home/vagrant/portfolio.
vagrant@ruby-jekyll-box:~$ cd portfolio/
vagrant@ruby-jekyll-box:~/portfolio$ jekyll serve
Configuration file: /home/vagrant/portfolio/_config.yml
            Source: /home/vagrant/portfolio
       Destination: /home/vagrant/portfolio/_site
      Generating...
                    done.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/home/vagrant/portfolio'
Configuration file: /home/vagrant/portfolio/_config.yml
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you trying to access it from inside the vagrant box? or from the computer you are running the vm on?  127.0.0.1 is localhost/loopback so 127.0.0.1 inside the vagrant box is not the same 127.0.0.1 on your computer.

try

```
jekyll serve --host=0.0.0.0
```

and then accessing it from your host computer at http://ip.of.vagrant.box:4000/

Comment: I was trying to access it from computer on which i'm running the VM, Your response explained me is all. Thanks.